# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not getting called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have a landscape app that I want to rotate 180 degress if the device is flipped. In my main view controller however, shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is not getting called at all. Why would that be?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    NSLog(@"ROTATE? %d", interfaceOrientation); //this never gets logged
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

EDIT: In the app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    [window addSubview:topViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Comment: Are you adding more than one controller's view to your window? 
See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html
(Technical Q&A QA1688
Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device?)

Comment: No. I will edit the post to show the app delegate.

Comment: Have you edited your Info.plist file to show that it supports both of those orientations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was editing the wrong view controller file (iphone vs ipad). The code above works. BTW @ughoavgfhw, editing the info.plist isn't necessary for this to happen.